# Is there a notion of inverse image for schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $Z$ be a subscheme of $Y$. Is there any reasonable way to talk about an "inverse image" of $Z$?

Comment: Yes, you want the pullback of the inclusion of $Z$!

Comment: It seems as if there are several competing interpretations of your question here between the comments and the answers. Could you add some clarity to your post with an [edit], please?

Answer (score 3):

The image of the natural morphism
$$
f^*I_Z \to f^*\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \mathcal{O}_X
$$
is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_X$. The corresponding subscheme of $X$ is a natural candidate for the inverse image of $Z$.

Comment: Does $I_Z$ still make sense if $Z$ is not closed in $X$?

Comment: No, as the vanishing locus of an ideal is always closed. If you want the inverse image of an open subscheme...well, such a thing is generally specified as the complement of a closed subscheme, so if $U = Y \setminus Z$ you could just take $f^{-1}(U) = X \setminus f^{-1}(Z)$, where $f^{-1}(Z)$ is as in Sasha's construction.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but why would you pick this? I would think the one in the comments, $X\times_Y Z$, is better suited - it does what I would think would be the right thing for immersions, for instance.

Comment: @HankScorpio: This is actually the same (essentially because tensor product is right exact).

Comment: @Sasha For open immersions, though? I agree about closed immersions.

Comment: @HankScorpio: For me a subscheme without adjective is a closed subscheme, so I was answering assuming this.